# Find usages in shelveset TFS

Tags: shelveset

Is there any way to use search in files in shelveset?
I have a shelveset with many shanged files. I want to find usages of some field of some class in this files. I dont want to get this version (and use search). But i dont want to open each file in shelveset too.

Comment: Why can't you just get the shelveset locally and search there?

Comment: There is nothing built in, unless some has created an extension, it's not going to be possible.